# How to extend submit button in Experience Manager

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager, siteedit

Is it possible modify the `..\Editors\SiteEdit\Views\Popups\NewContent\NewContent.aspx.js` file?

I lose product warranty doing that?

My goal is  extend the "**Create and insert content**" form button functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Editing anything other than user modifyable configuration files will indeed void your support contract.

To extend functionality in the CME or XPM, you have to use the Anguilla framework. See the [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-44562CE1-5D81-4E64-B65B-C8BFA0BAA53D) for more details.