# Tridion 8.5 UI Extension - How can I plug into rollback process?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

Context: component history screen, user clicks Rollback (Rollback command executes), a dialog appears with type of rollback (create new... vs delete all...), then user clicks Rollback button. At this moment, I want to do my stuff.

The problem is that if I plug into Rollback command, that happens BEFORE the dialog is displayed. I need to put my code AFTER the user clicks the Rollback button in the dialog.

Answer (score 7):

To trigger your custom the event handler after the Rollback button is clicked, you'd have to get the controls of the Rollback button and register your custom function on an onclick event. In your event handler, check if the view is `HistoryListDialog` and get the controls of the Rollback button using its id `RollbackBtn`. Then you can register your onclick custom event on the Rollback button.

[image]

Configure your GUI extension as you'd normally do and in the constructor of the JS, register a display event handler `$evt.addEventHandler($display, "start", this.getDelegate(this.onDisplay));`. And the rest of your JS should be something like this:

```
function onDisplay()
{
       var view = $display.getView().getId();

       if (view == "HistoryListDialog")
       {
              $display.resize();

              // Get the controls of the "Rollback" button using its id.
              var BtnRollback = $controls.getControl($("#RollbackBtn"), "Tridion.Controls.Button");

              // Register an onclick event on the "rollback" button
              $evt.addEventHandler(BtnRollback, "click", this.getDelegate(this.onBtnRollbackCustomClick_));
        }
}

function onBtnRollbackCustomClick_()
{    
      console.log("Rollback button clicked");
}
```

This [TREX post](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17625/extend-newcontent-aspx-window-in-experience-manager/17643#17643) might help too.